# Torque 3d hide scripts

Tags: scripting, share, torque3d

I can not find info about how hide my scripts and mesh files in proj's release. What if I don't want share my data (scripts and mesh)? Is it impossible with Torque 3d? Or must I buy a licensed version of the engine?

Comment: NOTE: I do not think I'll create something wonderful and unusual)) I'm interested from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: Torque is a program used to manage super computers. I'm only guessing but I think torque 3d is very different than torque. You have both programs tagged in your question. http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/